# trigger for not inserting members doesnt work

Tags: sql, triggers

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE members
(
    member_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    web_page VARCHAR(200),
    e_mail VARCHAR(200),
    cv VARCHAR(800),
    dep_id INT,
    teacher_id INT
);
```

and I want to create a trigger that if someone wants to insert a member which has a `dep_id` of `1` or `2` or `3`.

And the `teacher_id` is different than `NULL` (as the `teacher_id` column is filled with either `NULL` or an id of another member)

I came up with this

```
CREATE TRIGGER employee_insup1 
ON members
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @dep_id INT, @teacher_id INT

    SELECT @dep_id = i.dep_id, @teacher_id = i.teacher_id
    FROM inserted i
  
    IF ((@dep_id = 1) AND (@teacher_id != NULL))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Teacher_id expects NULL',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

but after all if I try to insert a member with `dep_id` `1` and `teacher_id` `7`(for example) it will be registered

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: If this is for SQL Server, then your trigger is fundamentally flawed. `inserted` holds a set of **all** the affected rows by one statement that triggered the trigger, not just only one row. So selecting from it columnwise into scalar variables is generally wrong.

Comment: Also: checking `!= NULL` will **fail** at all times - comparing against `NULL` **only** works with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` - anything else will always return `NULL` (or therefore: false)

Comment: Triggers are often a bad idea, and implemented the wrong way. Since you are updating the same table, seems to me that a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) could be sufficient. At least I would consider the idea. But more likely, what you really want in this case is a table constraint if the goal is to prevent some kind of data from being entered in the first place.

Comment: thnx guys so is there an alternative for the inserted? @sticky bit??

Comment: @BillZois: Again, if this is for SQL server (you still didn't tag the DBMS!) then no, there's no alternative, there's only the `inserted` pseudo table and per statement triggers.

Comment: yes its sql server thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trigger for this.  A check constraint is sufficient:

```
alter table members add constraint chk_members_dep_teacher
    check (dep_id not in (1, 2, 3) or teacher_id is not null);
```

Specifically, this ensures that when `dep_id` is in one of those departments, then the `teacher_id` is not null.  You might find the logic easier to follow as:

```
alter table members add constraint chk_members_dep_teacher
    check (not (dep_id nt in (1, 2, 3) and teacher_id is null) );
```